# IF conditional statement in Django template does not work

Tags: django, django-templates, conditional-statements

```
{% if user.resume %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
            start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>More information here</p>
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from users.models import User


class Resume(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render


@login_required()
def my_resumes(request):
    return render(request, 'resumes/myresumes.html')
```

I'm trying to place an empty state **if** a user does not have a resume. **Else,** I want to show other information. I can't seem to get it to work. I think I am using the `if` conditional statement wrong in the template.

Comment: Can you post your model and views here?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply @AstikAnand. I have updated my question to include the code you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your condition seems turned the wrong way. You code handling the case when the resume is not present is in the `if user.resume` statement. So it should rather be `if not user.resume`.

Second, the reverse relation is not named `user.resume` but `user.resume_set`. You can change this name using `related_name` if you want. For instance: `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='resumes')` would enable to access it via `user.resumes` instead of `user.resume_set`.

Yet, `if user.resume_set` will always be evaluated to `if True` because it is a related manager, not a queryset. So you could do something like this:

```
{% if not user.resume_set.exists %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
            start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>More information here</p>
{% endif %}
```

However, in your `else` statement, you will likely iterate over resumes with something like this `{% for resume in user.resume_set.all %}`. In such, case you will hit twice the database. Once for `user.resume_set.exists` and once for `user.resume_set.all`, which is not needed because you can know the result of `user.resume_set.exists` from the result of `user.resume_set.all`. Django templates allows you to do something like this to handle empty case when iterating an object:

```
{% for resume in user.resume_set.all %}
    Your code to display a resume item here
{% empty %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
            start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

But still, it is not very good practice to execute querysets in a template. To avoid this, you can pass it in your view:

```
@login_required()
def my_resumes(request):
    context = {'resumes': request.user.resume_set.all()}
    return render(request, 'resumes/myresumes.html', context)
```

Now you can do:

```
{% for resume in resumes %}
    Your code to display a resume item here
{% empty %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
            start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Note that you can also use the previous syntax, it will only hit the database once:

```
{% if not resumes %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
            start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>More information here</p>
    {% for resume in resumes %}
        Your code to display a resume item
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the backwards relationship on your resume class so you can access it using {{ user.resume }}.

By default the ForeignKey relationship you've defined from the resume to the user is accessible using user.resume_set. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for more detail.

I'm guessing that you only want to have a single resume per user, so you'll probably want to use a OneToOneField instead of a ForeignKey.

```
class Resume(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="resume")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Additionally, your if appears to be round the wrong way, given you probably want the form to appear when a resume doesn't exist.

```
{% if user.resume.exists %}
    <p>More information here</p>
{% else %}
    <div class="empty-state-box">
        <img src="{% static 'resumes/images/resume-empty-icon.png' %}" class="centered">
        <p class="empty-state-text"><b>You currently don't have any resumes.</b><br>Create one and
        start building your very first resume</p>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I thought the user object was accessible in the template.

Comment: It will be if you have the appropriate context processor enabled in your settings (django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth).

Comment: @ChristopherGunawan Yes, the user is accessible in the template.

Comment: Updated my answer given the original question seems to have been updated since I answered.